# GCM Android Client Not Firing WakefulService?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have literally followed the examples for implementing GCM inside an android app and the app is receiving the messages using the following code:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp;
        comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the GcmIntentService (**public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService**) is never being run? Am I missing something or should it usually fire the **onHandleIntent** method?

In case in any way related the Manifest file is below, thanks in advance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.diversivi.test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
                android:name=".DemoActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
                android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.diversivi.test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.diversivi.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.diversivi.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your `GcmIntentService` service declared in the manifest. That could be the problem.

In addition, the following line

```
comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

assumes that the `GcmIntentService` class is in the main package of your app (i.e. its full name is `com.diversivi.test.GcmIntentService`). If that's not the case, the broadcast receiver can't find the service class.

Comment: You know that time your stare at code so long you miss the most simple of things? Well turns out you are spot on! Thanks so much :-)